# How to extract the sequence of the edges responsible for the diameter in a igraph object in R?

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

Say a have an `igraph` object:

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
data(karate)


get_diameter(karate)
+ 6/34 vertices, named, from 4b458a1:
[1] Actor 16 John A   Actor 20 Mr Hi    Actor 6  Actor 17
farthest_vertices(karate)
$vertices
+ 2/34 vertices, named, from 4b458a1:
[1] Actor 16 Actor 17

$distance
[1] 13
```

I have easily found the vertices that are the farthest apart from each other. How do I extract the edges sequence that connects the vertices **Actor 16** to **Actor 17**?

Comment: `?get.all.shortest.paths` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

So the `diameter` is the longest `shortest_path` of the graph. Luckily, the `shortest_paths` function can give you both the node vector (`vpath`) and the edge vector (`epath`). The output is a list, and if you want to get the edge vector, then you'll need to set the parameter `output = 'both` or `output='epath'`

```
shortest_paths(karate, 'Actor 16', 'Actor 17', output = 'both')$epath[[1]]
```

Or, if you want to figure this out dynamically:

```
farthest_vertices(karate)$vertices %>% 
  {shortest_paths(karate, .[1], .[2], output = 'both')} %>%
  .$epath %>%
  .[[1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well actually `get_diameter` does give you the edge sequence between the two nodes :

```
[1] Actor 16 John A   Actor 20 Mr Hi    Actor 6  Actor 17
```

In the function documentation :

> get_diameter returns a path with the actual diameter. If there are many shortest paths of the length of the diameter, then it returns the first one found.

Comment: That's a list of vertices, not a list of edges. Two vertices can have multiple edges between them. Also, some functions require an actual edge list, not just the vertices the edges connect

Comment: OK my bad, so you are right, shortest_path is the answer !